# Create a slider with arrow keys and with the mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, codepen

How to pass slides with the keys without this repetition effect happening with the setInterval, when I have the mouse over the container and at the same time press the key to go through images

this is the codepen https://codepen.io/AlainBarrios/pen/BPayXO?editors=0010

The commented thing is the arrowKeys function that I did to move the images with the keys but it does not work at all well, a strange effect happens and I imagine that it has to do with the setInterval.

```
const arrowKeys = () => {
    window.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
        if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
            prevControl.click();
            return false
        } else if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
            nextControl.click();
            return false
        }
    });
};

if (keyboard === "true") {
    arrowKeys();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What strange effect?

Comment: When you use the arrow keys with the mouse on the container, a strange animation like flicker occurs

Answer (score 0):

Use the onkeydown event listener

Keycodes:

```
const arrowKeys = () => {
    window.addEventListener("onkeydown", e => {
        if (e.key === 37) {
            prevControl.click();
            return false
        } else if (e.key === 39) {
            nextControl.click();
            return false
        }
    });
};

if (keyboard === "true") {
   arrowKeys();
}
```